# Trying to find a way to center multiple elements inside of a div class in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a good enough knowledge of HTML, but I am just stuck with something related to my responsive design HTML CSS code. I was following the W3 Schools webpage showing how to create a Navbar for a website ([Link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp)).

Here is my current CSS file and `index.html`:

```css
body {
    background-color: #FAEBD7;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.top-navbar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.top-navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.top-navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.top-navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Centered section inside the top navigation */
.top-navbar a {
/* float: none; */
/*   position: absolute; */
/*   top: 50%; */
/*   left: 50%; */
/*   transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
}


/* Responsive navigation menu - display links on top of each other instead of next to each other (for mobile devices) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .top-navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }

  .topnav-centered a {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FUBS</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Elder Scrolls, Fallout, Information, Wiki">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src = "http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="top-navbar">
  <a class="active link" href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a class="link" href="scrolls/index-scrolls.html">The Elder Scrolls</a>
  <a class="link" href="fallout/index-fallout.html">Fallout</a>
</div>

<div class="test-div">
</div>

<div style="padding:0 16px;">
<br />

etc. etc. etc.

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you run the above code snippet you will get an idea of what I want it to do (If you drag your window smaller you will see the change).

Basically, what I just want to do is to have the nav bar links to be centered (Along with the black bar that goes across the screen). I already have it so that when the screen size if below 600 pixels, it switches to that effect.

I narrowed down the part of the tutorial that was making my nav bar disappear. It has the above from the `@media` part of the CSS (You will see that it is commented out). In the tutorial, the centered part of the class `topnav-centered` had only one element, an `a` tag. Maybe because in my website it has more than one element in the class that it is refusing to work? That is just my guess though.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is a little unclear. When the screen is larger than 600px do you want the menu items centered? Spaced evenly?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to have the menu items to be centered in the middle of the page. I followed Connor's answer below and that seemed to have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the items aren't centered is because the `a` tags are floated to the left, this will always force them to the left.

To fix this you just need to amend the 2 classes below, adding `text-align: center;` as well as removing the float and setting your links to `display: inline-block;` will allow you to control their position.

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.top-navbar {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.top-navbar a {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, It seams that the links appear to be centered, but now the colums that you would experience if you drag your window to less than 600 pixels is now gone. It is now just a one line navbar, instead of a columnized nav bar if the screen is less than 600 pixels.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind, I actually deleted another .top-navbar class being used that seemed to conflict with another .top-navbar class, thanks for your help.